# I want to hook the constructor of jdk method, it doesn't work for java.io.File class

Tags: byte-buddy

I use the constructor of byte buddy hook jdk, I found that java.io.Reader() can get the constructor information, but new File(),new FileWriter() can't. Is there any way to achieve it?

test code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("ss");
        UncheckedIOException outputStream = new UncheckedIOException(new IOException());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    File file = new File("D:\\test.json");
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    UserDO userDO = new UserDO();
}
```

byte buddy code

```
AgentBuilder agentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .disableClassFormatChanges()
            .with(RETRANSFORMATION)
            .ignore(none())
            .ignore(
                    nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy.")
                            .or(nameStartsWith("jdk.internal.reflect."))
                            .or(nameStartsWith("java.lang.invoke."))
                            .or(nameStartsWith("com.sun.proxy."))
                            .or(nameStartsWith("com.bc.horizon.fuzzing.agent"))
                            .or(nameStartsWith("org.slf4j."))
                            .or(nameStartsWith("io.grpc.netty."))
                            .or(nameContains("javassist"))
                            .or(nameContains("org.jacoco"))
                            .or(nameContains(".asm."))
                            .or(nameContains(".reflectasm.")))
            .disableClassFormatChanges()
            .with(RETRANSFORMATION)
            .with(new AgentListener())
            .with(AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE)
            .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
            .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REBASE);

      agentBuilder.type(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("java.io")
            .or(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("java.net")))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
                    builder.method(any())
                            .intercept(Advice.to(SanitizerAdvice.class))
                            .constructor(ElementMatchers.any())
                            .intercept(Advice.to(ConstructorMethodAdvice.class)))
            .installOn(inst);
```

Results of the

```
constructor public java.io.StringReader(java.lang.String)
constructor protected java.io.Reader()
constructor public java.io.StringReader(java.lang.String)
constructor protected java.io.Reader()
constructor protected java.io.Reader()
```

Is there any way I can get the constructor of File()?

Comment: The latest execution result, you can get new FileWriter(), but still can't get the constructor of new File().
constructor public java.io.FileWriter(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
constructor public java.io.UncheckedIOException(java.io.IOException)
constructor public java.io.StringReader(java.lang.String)
constructor protected java.io.Reader()

Comment: Does the listener confirm that the file class is instrumented?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm listening on the file class, I found out using this builder.visit(Advice.to(SanitizerConstructorAdvice.class)
  .on(isConstructor()))) method to get the constructor information of the File class

Comment: But did you add a listener that confirms that the class is instrumented (or ignored)?